# Symfony2 Google API, How to use Google client

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, google-calendar-api

I am using Symfony2.3 and I want to access Google Calendar API, here what i did 
1-I installed [HIWO Bundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) and [FOSUser Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)
2-Integrated both bundles and now i have user authenticated and inserted into database with access token
3-I have installed [Google API library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and auto-loaded it
4-created a Service wrapper class to access

**Problem 1 :** 
Seems now i m using Oauth2 found in HIWO Bundle while logging in and I will be using Oauth2 in Google API library while making request, which dosent make any sense and not sure what should be done in this matter

**Trials:**
-I found out that token provided by HIW Oauth is not the same as the one in `code` parameter in URL while redirecting back 
-Tried to set token manually and try to intiat simulate Google client request `$cal = new \Google_Calendar($this->googleClient)` as below but

```
    $this->googleClient->authenticate('4/PmsUDPCbxWgL1X_akVYAhvnVWqpn.ErqFdB3R6wMTOl05ti8ZT3Zpgre8fgI');
    return $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();`
```

Error received:

> Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'redirect_uri_mismatch'

and i made sure i have `redirect_uri` matched

My Service code is as below :

```
<?php

namespace Clinic\MainBundle\Services;

use Clinic\MainBundle\Entity\Patient;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

/*
 * @author: Ahmed Samy
 */

class GoogleInterfaceService {
    /*
     * Entity manager
     */

    protected $em;
    /*
     * instance of Symfphony session
     */
    protected $session;
    /*
     * Service container
     */
    protected $container;

    /*
     * Google client instance
     */
    protected $googleClient;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em, $container) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->googleClient = new \Google_Client();

        $this->googleClient->setClientId('xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
        $this->googleClient->setClientSecret('uNnaK1o-sGH_pa6Je2jfahpz');
        $this->googleClient->setRedirectUri('http://hacdc.com/app_dev.php/login/check-google');
        $this->googleClient->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        $this->googleClient->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");
    }

    public function getCalendar() {

        $cal = new \Google_Calendar($this->googleClient);

        //setting token manually 
        $this->googleClient->authenticate('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        return $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
    }

}
```

and when i dump `$this->googleClient` i get

```
protected 'scopes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'useObjects' => boolean false
  protected 'services' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'authenticated' => boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

The HWIOAuthBundle's token is missing the `created` array segment, but you could force that in there, and then just feed that token to the client like so:

```
    $googleAccessToken = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getRawToken();
    $googleAccessToken['created'] = time(); // This is obviously wrong... but you get the poing

    $this->google_client->setAccessToken(json_encode($googleAccessToken));

    $activities = $this->google_plusservice->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');

    var_dump($activities);die();
```